# Remmina doesn't work with keyboard when connected remotely

Tags: ubuntu, remmina

In order to bypass firewall/GPO constraint, I want to use Ubuntu as springboard to rdp to a Windows box on the same LAN remotely. I can `xrdp` to ubuntu via sesman-Xvnc module. I can run `remmina` from the `vnc` session. But in the `remmina` Windows session, keyboard doesn't work at all. Only mouse works. Keyboard works with other apps in `vnc` session. Also, if I use remmina at local Ubuntu console, keyboard works.

Any suggestions?